# Named semaphore or flock which is better C linux

Tags: c, concurrency, multiprocessing, semaphore, flock

I am trying to create a shared memory which will be used by multiple processes. these processes communicate with each other using `MPI` calls (`MPI_Send`, `MPI_Recv`).

I need a mechanism to control the access of this shared memory I added a question yesterday to see if MPI provides any facility to do that. [Shared memory access control mechanism for processes created by MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081802/shared-memory-access-control-mechanism-for-processes-created-by-mpi) , but it seems that there is no such provision by MPI.

So I have to choose between `named semaphore` or `flock`.

For named semaphore if any of the process dies abruptly without calling `sem_cloe()`, than that semaphore always remains and can be seen by `ll /dev/shm/`. This results in deadlock sometimes(if I run the same code again!), for this reason I am currently thinking of using flock.

Just wanted to confirm if `flock` is best suited for this type of operation ?

Are there any disadvantages of using `flock`?

Is there anything else apart from `named semaphore` and `flock` that can be used here ?

I am working on C under linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use a POSIX mutex in shared memory; you just have to set the "pshared" attribute on it first. See [`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html). This is arguably the most direct way to do what you want.

That said, you can also call [`sem_unlink`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_unlink.html) on your named semaphore while you are still using it. This will remove it from the file system, but the underlying semaphore object will continue to exist until the last process calls `sem_close` on it (which happens automatically if the process exits or crashes).

I can think of two minor disadvantages to using `flock`. First, it is not POSIX, so it makes your code somewhat less portable, although I believe most Unixes implement it in practice. Second, it is implemented as a system call, so it will be slower. Both `pthread_mutex_lock` and `sem_wait` use the "futex" mechanism on Linux, which only does a system call when you actually have to wait. This is only a concern if you are grabbing and releasing the lock a lot.

Comment: +1, but I'd just like to add that `flock` and similar mechanisms are certainly not a good choice. They are designed to protect concurrent use of files and for nothing else. In particular, if nothing else is happening on the file, it is not specified when file meta-data (such as locks) is visible for other processes. Just don't use this for a purpose it was not designed for.